# Error : unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been through similar questions, but not able to solve my issue.
The issue is i have a call to API and i am storing the response in a `NSDictionary`, the response is a single value like `RED` or `GREEN`:

```
saveBlock:^( NSDictionary *data, NSError **err )
{
    if (! *err)
    {
         if (data)
         {
             NSLog(@"KEY %@ - VALUE %@",data.allKeys,data.allValues); //Error because i am performing .allKeys on type NSString
             NSString *str = data; // error because i am assigning NSDictionary to string.
         }
     }
     else
     {
        NSLog(@" error is : - %@",*err);
     }
}];
```

Aren't these two error messages contradicting each other ? Anyone explanation about this issue. Thank you.

**EDIT** The first `NSLog` gives this error : `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170664b80'`
(This error appears only at runtime and not when i type data.allKeys)

And the second `NSLog` gives this: Incompatible pointer type, initialising NSString* with an expression of type `NSDictionary *`
(This is shown after typing, i don't know what this type of error is called :D)

Comment: Please show the detail of the exception message - what was the object type and what was the selector that was invoked?  From your comments it seems that `data` is a string, so you should change your block to `saveBlock:^( NSString *data, NSError **err )` and not try to access keys and values

Comment: does the first error happen at run time?

Comment: @Paulw11 - Sorry i cannot change NSDictionary to NSString, it's a huge project i am working on.

Comment: @Fonix- Yes, the first one is a runtime error.

Comment: The problem is that Objective-C, like C *trusts* you, so if you say that `data` is an `NSDictionary *` then it won't complain at compile time if you use `NSDictionary` messages, such as `allKeys`.  It does complain when you try and assign it to an `NSString *` because you said it was a dictionary.  Now, at run time if you pass an `NSString *` to this method (which is what you are doing) then you will get an exception when you try and treat it like a dictionary, because it isn't one!  So you can either change what you pass to this method or you can change the parameter type

Comment: It may be that you need to change your server-side API to return a dictionary rather than a string.  Where does `data` come from?

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks a lot, there was another block defined which had NSData as first parameter instead of NSDictionary, so i could assign it to a NSString.

Comment: @Paulw11 But in case if there was no other block defined like i mentioned above, is changing the server side API the only option, sorry but i am new and learning.

Comment: As I said, how do you get `data` from the server response?  Whatever process you are using is giving you a string, not a dictionary.  What do you see if you `NSLog(data);` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106674/discussion-between-tkutal-and-paulw11).

Answer (score 0):

It is a standard practice to check your response type and error message before performing any operation, sort of defensive coding.

eg.

```
     DLog(@"Object:%@,Error:%@",responseObject,error);
     if (error != nil) {
         DLog(@"Got error from API:%@",error);
         return ;
     }
     if (!responseObject) {
         DLog(@"Response object is not valid, returning...");
         return;
     }
     if (![responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
         DLog(@"Incorrect type of returned object, expecting NSDictionary, got:%@",[responseObject class]);
         return;
     }
```

Also I am pretty sure you are getting a `NSString` cause you don't get an error when assigning a `NSDictionary` to a `NSString`

Answer (score 0):

Webservice response data 'data' should be NSDictionary, but in your case you are getting NSString. For NSString class, there is no allKeys method available, that is why you are getting crash. One thing is to validate for NSDictionary like.

```
if (data && [data isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {

NSLog(@"KEY %@ - VALUE %@",data.allKeys,data.allValues); //Error because i am performing .allKeys on type NSString
NSString *str = data; // error because i am assigning NSDictionary to string
}
```

Or remove NSLog